# Data is not retrieved from MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have HTML CODE

```
  <form action="authentication.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" id="txtbox" class="txt_box" name="user" value="Username" />
            <input type="password" id="txtbox1" class="txt_box_pass" name="pass" value="Password" /><br />
            <div id="radio">



    <input type="submit" value=" " name="submit" class="submit" />
    </div>

  </form>
```

This code is placed in `authentication.php` file:

```
<?php


$dbvar = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart"); 

//Check Database Conectivity

if(mysqli_errno())
{
    "Failed to connect to database" . mysqli_error();
}

$query = "select * from admin where first_name = '$_POST[user]' and password = '$_POST[pass]'";

$check = mysqli_query($dbvar,$query);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($count != 0)
{
    header('location: upload_product_code.php');
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

I have only one value in the table, so it should pick it up when i enter valid username and password. But it display an error called
    Warning: mysqli_errno() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\php\Mobil India\authentication.php on line 16

and follwed by text Wrong username and password. How can i make it work, so that when i enter valid values i should be redirected to the specified page.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection as you are putting raw $_POST variables into an SQL string. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @Cole can you please show me what to do and how to do?

Comment: Sure, check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation for mysqli_errno?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php

When called in that manner, you must supply a link identifier as an argument, hence the warning and the error.

Comment: as you wrote i added the link, now the error is removed, but the query is not running yet. Still it shows wrong username and password even after adding the correct one.

Comment: @SahibjotSingh if you fixed this error and still have another error you need to edit your question and add the new error/problem that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about '$_POST[user]' and not "'.$_POST[user].'" ?

Comment: This is what i get with this query

 Use of undefined constant pass - assumed 'pass' in C:\wamp\www\php\Mobil India\authentication.php on line 21

Comment: you need to use quotation marks when calling elements of an array like `$_POST["user"]`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$usr=$_POST['user'];
$psw=$_POST['pass'];
```

and then write your query like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ADMIN WHERE first_name= '$usr' AND password='$psw'
```

I think that this will do the job, sometimes using directly POST or GET values on Query string can make people mad :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the query like this:

```
$query = "select * from admin where first_name = '" . $_POST[user] . "' and password = '"  . $_POST[pass] . "'";
```

Comment: This does not address the question about the error occurring on the "mysqli_errno" call.

Comment: this answer still has error in it... you need to use quotation marks when calling elements of an array like `$_POST["user"]`